# read patterns from file1 and search them iteratively in file2

Tags: text-processing, awk, search

I'd like to read patterns from file1 and search them iteratively in file2, printing the matched line plus 3 rows, and print them to file3.

Now I am doing:

```
cat file1 | while read line; do awk '/$line/ {for(i=1; i<=3; i++) {getline; print}}' file2 > file3 ; done
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this? My irl files are quite big (~30GB)

Comment: You could read the lines from file1 without using `cat`. See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/) for syntax.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like `grep -f file1 -A3 file2 > file3`

Comment: @steeldriver, sounds good. but I have to test if runtime is acceptable. usualy grep takes longer than awk on big files.

Comment: Well, if you do decide to use awk, you should be passing $line into it using something like `awk -v pat="$line"` and then testing it using `$0 ~ pat` rather than trying to use shell variable `/$line/` inside the awk regex.

Comment: There is no possible way that a shell `while read loop` around `awk` (or anything, for that matter ) is going to be faster than just using `grep` (in your case, `grep -f file1 ...`).  A `while read` loop is one of the slowest ways to read data from a file.  BTW, GNU grep is extremely fast, anyway.

Comment: Putting `> file3` *inside* the loop would overwrite *file3* with every pass of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You scan the file once for each pattern. It would be a lot faster to go through the file only once, especially since the file doesn't fit in cache.

Your sample code actually only saves the matches from the last pattern in `file1`. I assume that this is an oversimplification. If you need all the matches in a single file, then it's as if the patterns were joined together with the “or” operator.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        while (getline <"file1") pattern = pattern "|" $0;
        pattern = substr(pattern, 2);
    }
    match($0, pattern) {for(i=1; i<=3; i++) {getline; print}}
' file2 > file3
```

Note also that this doesn't print the matched line, only the three following lines. If you actually wanted to print the matched line before the three following lines, you need an additional `print;` before the `for` loop.

If you actually wanted to print the matched line before the three following lines, and your `grep` command supports the `-A` argument, then you should use this instead. A specialized program like grep is usually faster than an interpreted language like awk. As an added bonus, the command is a lot simpler.

```
grep -A -E -f file1 file2 >file3
```

If you've found that grep is slower, it might be because you've run into a defect of GNU grep in multibyte locales: it can sometimes be very slow, even when neither the file nor the pattern contains multibyte characters. If you aren't using character classes to match non-ASCII characters (e.g. you don't use `[[:alpha:]]` to match all Unicode letters) then run grep in a unibyte locale:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -A3 -E -f file1 file2 >file3
```

The output of grep isn't exactly the same as the awk snippet because they behave differently if the pattern is found in one of the lines being printed due to a previous line. For example, if the pattern is `a` and the lines are `a1`,`a2`,`b`,`c`,`d` then `grep -A3` prints `a1`,`a2`,`b`,`c` whereas the awk snippet above prints `a2`,`b`,`c` and the awk snippet with the additional `print` prints `a1`,`a2`,`b`,`c`.